# Почему не подгружается кастомный атрибут?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть Клиника, у которой много Врачей. У Врача есть кастомное свойство "custom_atr", которое я хочу добавить к выдаче (знаю что можно прописать в классе модели protected $appends = ['custom_atr'];, но это будет распространяться всегда.)

Вот код.

```
$clinic = $clinic->find(1);
$clinic->load([
    'doctors' => function ($q) {
        $q->each(function ($doctor) {
            $doctor->append('custom_atr');
        });
    }
]);
```

После сериализации этого поля у Доктора нет.

Comment: возможно нужно добавить return ?

Comment: Ответ получил на другом ресурсе. https://toster.ru/q/643202